# Using SQLite with Entity Framework in Windows Phone

Tags: entity-framework, sqlite, windows-phone-8

I want to ask you if it is possible to use SQLite with Entity Framework in Windows Phone 8 application? Or Entity Framework cannot be used for local database (SQLite) in Windows Phone application?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you could use `SQLite` in your WP application by downloading the `extension` from VS.

[Reference](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/642845/SQLite-for-Windows-Phone)

And also you could use it as a local database too. Could get a better idea from here :

[Windows phone 8.1 Local Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26411865/)

Comment: Yeah but I already have `SQLite` in my WP application. I just converted my SQL Server database schema to SQLite file and put it as my SQLite local database in my application. But now I have a problem with retrieving data from SQLite. I don't have classes which describe tables etc. How can I retrieve (`SELECT`) some data without that classes? I would like to use ORM like `Entity Framework` but I can't do that so I am afraid that EF is not available in WP applications.

Comment: Otherwise - can I generate classes (which represent tables) from an existing `SQLite` database in my WP application?

Comment: This might help: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/826602/Using-SQLite-as-local-database-with-Universal-Apps
Also note that EF 7 will support WP.