# ado.net entity data model not available for WP8 and UWP

Tags: .net, entity-framework, windows-phone-8, ado.net, win-universal-app

Hi I starded learning recently wp8 and uwp, but I cannot find "ado.net entity data model" project item. When I create a WPF application it is available, but in widows phone 8, 8.1 and UWP it is not available. Is this a bug, or is it not available for mobile projects?
I am using VS2015 Community

Comment: No, Entity framework doesn't support in windows phone 8 project, Instead of you could try `sqllite`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **cannot** using `Entity framework` directly in the windows phone project.

*You could use EF in your web-service or api and use the service to communicate with your phone clients*

> Starting with Windows Phone OS 7.1, you can store relational data in a local database that resides in your app’s local folder. Windows Phone apps use LINQ to SQL for all database operations; LINQ to SQL is used to define the database schema, select data, and save changes to the underlying database file residing in the local folder. This topic provides an overview of using a local database with your Windows Phone app. For a step-by-step walkthrough of creating an app that uses a local database [Msdn Refernece](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/apps/hh202860(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_CreatingtheDatabase)

**you could use `SQLite` instead of `Entity framework` in your WP application** [Sample 1](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/642845/SQLite-for-Windows-Phone)

See similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28354986/using-sqlite-with-entity-framework-in-windows-phone) in stack